# Renderscript GLSL shader converting all uniforms to floats

Tags: android, renderscript

When creating a custom shader in GLSL for renderscript the program builder seems to be converting all the members of structure I bind as uniform constants to floats or vec, regardless of what their specified type is. Also, I have a uniform that is reporting at compile time the following error: "Could not link program, L0010, Uniform "uniform name here" differ on precision.". I have the same named uniform in two different structures that separately bind to the vertex and fragment shaders.

[EDIT]
Thanks for the answer to the second part. In regards to the first part I will try to be more clear. When building my shader programs in the java side, I bind constants to the program builders (both vertex and fragment) with the input being a the java variable that is bound to a renderscript structure. Everything works great, all my float variables are completely accessable as uniforms in the shader programs. However, if the structure has a member such as bool or int types and I attempt something such as if (i == UNI_memberInt) where i is  an integer counter declared in the shader or if (UNI_memberBool) then I get errors along the lines of "cannot compare int to float" or "if() condition must be of a boolean type" which suggests to me that the data is not making it to the GLSL program intact. I can get around this by making them float values and using things like 0.0 since GLSL requires the float value of 0 to always be exact but it seems crude to me. Similar things occur if I try and use UNI_memberInt as a stop condition in a for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for asking this at the developer hangout. Unfortunately an engineer on the Renderscript team doesn't quite understand the first part of your question. If you can clarify that would be great. As for the second part, it is a known bug.

Basically, if you have a uniform "foo" in both the vertex and fragment shader, the vertex shader is high precision, and the fragment shader is medium, which the GLSL compiler can't handle. Unfortunately, the solution is to not have any name collisions between the two.